# Why am I getting a null value for my div?

Tags: angular

I have a component that takes an input. The component contains a div, where the "id" value is set using property binding with one of the properties of the input.

html

```html
<div class="container">
    <div [id]=schema.id class="tabulator-container">fdsafa</div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```js
export class TabulatorUserTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() schema: TableSchema;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(document.getElementById(this.schema.id));
  }
}
```

If I inspect the element, the div exists and is assigned the expected id.

When I call `console.log(document.getElementById(this.schema.id))`, `null` is returned.

Comment: Try using the [`AfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview) lifecycle hook rather than `OnInit`.

Comment: The real question is why are you selecting an element at all? Angular is meant to separate concerns such that you don't need to interact with the DOM.

Comment: This was the approach given on a tabulator example. I'd be happy to take your advice on a better solution if you're willing to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`AfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) instead of `OnInit`:

```
export class TabulatorUserTableComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() schema: TableSchema;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(document.getElementById(this.schema.id));
  }
}
```

According to the [Angular lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence):

> `ngAfterViewInit()`
>
> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child
> views, or the view that contains the directive.